# Removing columns from Dataframe by frequency of missing values & whether percentage of unique values is above / lower than a specified threshold

Tags: python, criteria, threshold, drop

Write python function with input_df,threshold and unique threshold as arguments.[image: Section of Dataframe]

```
train_df = input_df.copy()
num_unique = []

for item in train_df[column]:
    if item not in num_unique and not pd.isnull(item):
        num_unique.append(item)

col_unique_percentage = (len(num_unique) / len(train_df[column])) * 100
for column in train_df:
    count_nan = train_df[column].isna().sum()
    nan_freq =  (count_nan / len(train_df[column]))*100    
    if (col_unique_percentage < unique_value_threshold) and (nan_freq > threshold):
        train_df = train_df.drop[column]
```

[image: Expected Output]